# Making a multi page form in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, user-interface

so I want to make a multipage form that has a linear progress indicator at the top instead of the normal stepper widget one, I've tried SO many different websites and nothing is both working and has everything I need,

what I want is:

- to have a different page for each step
- a way to return the data collected from each step
- a bar at the top to show how close you are to finishing the form
- and a way to edit each page serperately

any advice on how I'd do this would be so so so appreciated and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first, it's a shorthand solution (fast solution) for your problem.

the below code should be refactored and and can be enhanced, but i'm presenting an idea.
here's the code, the coming is the driver class that manages the Linear Progress Indicator(LPI) and page view.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var pages =  [ FirstPage(),SecondPage(), ThirdPage(),FourthPage(),];

  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('called');
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
             Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 30),
               child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                 color: Colors.blue.shade700,
                 value: (currentIndex+1) /4,
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                 minHeight: 20,
               ),
             ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: PageView(
                  children: pages,
                  onPageChanged: (i){
                    setState(() {
                      currentIndex = i;
                    });
                  },
                  padEnds: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ok, pages variable is a list of widgets, in which every widget holds the presented content in every page. *it's a page view*

look at `FirstPage` Widget implementation

```
class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {

  static var controller = TextEditingController();
  const FirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              label: Text('Name'),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.blue)
            )
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

here's second page, regardless the number of pages you have. the third page will have the same implementation like the others.

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static var controller = TextEditingController();
  const SecondPage({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: Text('phone'),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.blue)
              )
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

if you notice every page (class) has a controller for its text field which enables us to get the written text at last.

the last page of page view

```
class FourthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static var controller = TextEditingController();
  const FourthPage({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('Fourth Page'),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          onFieldSubmitted: (s){
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=> FinalScreen(),
                    settings: RouteSettings(
                      arguments: {
                        'first' : FirstPage.controller.text,
                        'second' : SecondPage.controller.text,
                        'third' : ThirdPage.controller.text,
                        'fourth' : FourthPage.controller.text
                      },
                    )
                )
            );
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              label: Text('Password'),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.blue)
              )
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**the fourth and last page has a critical lines of code that are executed when user submits the value to text field( it navigate to the home or final page and send data to that page using route settings ).**

here's the final page which presents user gathered data

```
class FinalScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FinalScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map<String,String>;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Final Screen'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('first page data: ${data['first']}'),
            Text('second page data: ${data['second']}'),
            Text('third page data: ${data['third']}'),
            Text('fourth page data: ${data['fourth']}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

notice:

- the above code doesn't make text input validation, you should do
  (wrap them with form *you know*) and validate user input on each page
  view swipe. if the input violates your rules swipe back to the
  previous page and alert the user (use  page view controller).
- thirdPage isn't provided because it has the same implementation just
  like the first and second.

here's the output:
[image]

hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you so so so so much this is absolutely perfect I CANNOT thank you enough

Comment: how do you navigate to the next page?

Comment: @Sebastian , hi there, as you know page view widget manages the navigation between its children, you just swipe the screen and it navigate to the next child. while navigating to another different route (Final Page) i'm using basic routing technique by Navigator class and passing user's data.

Comment: it doesnt seem to be working for me, is it possible to make a button at the bottom of the page to swap between pages?

Comment: aha, i have mentioned in the answer to make a programmatic navigation to the page view, this can be done using page view controller try to search about it and how to use the function animateTo to navigate to specific page. this logic should be contained inside onPressed of your button, you can handle it. see [**page Controller**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html)