# I want to create multi page form in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, bloc, flutter-bloc

ı want to create step by step form but ı cant make it ı have been strugling about 2 weeks. Fİrst of
ı want to creat screen like in the left.
I will bring a different form to the screen according to the option selected at first. a Page with dropdownbutton and form states not only string values some of them are maps list etc
. And in the last step,I want to send the data I have received from different forms to send to firebase. But one of
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzZx6.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Please provide some code snippets or the state-management solution you are using

Comment: check that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996973/making-a-multi-page-form-in-flutter/77998235#77998235)

Comment: but mine data types not a string in second page ı have 5 dropdownmenu and ı have to convert to map and hold and the next page ı have to upload images convert to string and ı want to hold as a List<String> etc

Comment: mine repository is https://github.com/KaanMasc/realestate here. ı am sturgling post_ad_page

Answer (score 0):

You can try pageview for that just make the PageView with physics NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
now whenever you want to go from one page to another just call PageView Controller function

```
controller.animateToPage(2ndPageIndex,duration:Duration.zero)
```

But here you need to handle all values at higher level for both pages with some default value and pass them to pages.